# Why is Spark2 running on only one node?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-2.0

I am running Spark2 from Zeppelin (0.7 in HDP 2.6) and I am doing an idf transformation which crashes after many hours. It is run on a cluster with a master and 3 datanodes: s1, s2 and s3. All nodes have a Spark2 client and each has 8 cores and 16GB RAM.

I just noticed it is only running on one node, s3, with 5 executors.

In zeppelin-env.sh I have set `zeppelin.executor.instances` to 32 and `zeppelin.executor.mem` to 12g and it has the line:

```
export MASTER=yarn-client
```

I have set `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class` to `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler`.

I also set `spark.executor.instances` to 32 in the Spark2 interpreter.

Anyone have any ideas what else I can try to get the other nodes doing their share?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because I am an idiot. Only S3 had datanode and nodemanager installed. Hopefully this might help someone.